# Configuring assets error - Could not resolve host: s3.amazonaws.com

Tags: assets, aws, amazon

I'm running a craft project (ver. 2.4.2684). When I try to upload assets, the progress bar fills and the spinner continues to spin. It looks like it just stalls out and doesn't go beyond that point.

When I go into my settings and into my AWS setup, I get this image when I try to refresh my bucket:

```
S3::listBuckets(): [6] Could not resolve host: s3.amazonaws.com
```

Not sure what the issue is since I did not have issues uploading assets before (they still appear loaded into the CMS and are still displaying when I visit the page). For some reason it just won't allow me to upload more assets.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related to the Ubuntu update that killed DNS for everyone today? https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3239-1/  Rebooting the server seems to resolve it for most people.